# The CI and standard error of indirect effect in Mediation analysis

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, standard-error, mediation

When I do causal mediation analysis in R package mediation::mediate(), I need to print out the standard error of the indirect effect estimate. However, I suppose there is no such output? I have two questions as following,

1. Is there anyway to get the SE based on this function output?
2. The output gives me the CI. And I try to calculate the SE based on

   'estimate + 1.96*SE = CI upper limit'

   'estimate - 1.96*SE = CI lower limit'.

However, the estimate is not equal to  '(CI upper limit + lower limit)/2', and I don't think this is an appropriate way to calculate the SE. Could you please give me any suggestions for this case? Thank you very much!